# Mongoimport to merge/upsert fields

Tags: mongodb, upsert, database

I'm trying to import and merge multiple CSVs into mongo, however documents are getting replaced rather than merged.

For example, if I have one.csv:

```
key1, first column, second column
```

and two.csv:

```
key1, third column
```

I would like to end up with:

```
key1, first column, second column, third column
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
key1,third column
```

Currently I'm using:

```
mongoimport.exe --ftype csv --file first.csv --fields key,firstColumn,secondColumn
mongoimport.exe --ftype csv --file second.csv --fields key,thirdColumn --upsert --upsertFields key1
```

Comment: Mongoimport doesnt support this (see johnnyhk below). Ended up doing this in pymongo: collection.update({"keyfield": "key"}, {"$set": {"field": "data"}})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way `mongoimport` works.  There's an existing [new feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1674) for merge imports, but for now, you'll have to write your own import to provide merge behavior.

Answer (score 3):

cross-collection workaround: forEach method can be run on a dummy collection and the resulting doc objects used to search/update your desired collection:

```
mongoimport.exe --collection mycoll --ftype csv --file first.csv --fields key,firstColumn,secondColumn
mongoimport.exe --collection dummy --ftype csv --file second.csv --fields key,third

db.dummy.find().forEach(function(doc) {db.mycoll.update({key:doc.key},{$set:{thirdcol:doc.third}})})
```

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, mongoimport --upsert updates full documents.
You may achieve your goal by importing to a temporary collection and using the following [Gist](https://gist.github.com/kerkero/2a2344ac47eede070d28).

Load the script to Mongo Shell and run:

```
mergeCollections("srcCollectionName", "destCollectionName", {}, ["thirdColl"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar problem.  There is a node module for mongo and jline is my command line node tool for stream processing JSON lines.  So:

```
echo '{"page":"index.html","hour":"2015-09-18T21:00:00Z","visitors":1001}' |\
jline-foreach \
    'beg::dp=require("bluebird").promisifyAll(require("mongodb").MongoClient).connectAsync("mongodb://localhost:27017/nginx")' \
    'dp.then(function(db){
       updates = {}
       updates["visitors.hour."+record.hour] = record.visitors;
       db.collection("pagestats").update({_id:record.page},{$set:updates},{upsert:true});});' \
    'end::dp.then(function(db){db.close()})'
```

In your case you'd have to convert from csv to JSON lines first by piping it through `jline-csv2jl`.  That converts each CSV line into a dictionary with names taken from the header.

I have added this example to the manual: https://github.com/bitdivine/jline/blob/master/bin/foreach.md

I haven't used jline with promises much but so far it's OK.

Disclaimer: I am the author of jline.