# upserting mongoDB collection with CSV file

Tags: java, mongodb, csv

i have one mongoDB collection which have follwing value

```
        lat    long   band1
       23.454  56.454  67
```

i want to updated that collection so that i get follwing collection

```
      lat     long    band1  band2
      23.454  56.454  67      73
```

csv which i want to use for update is  contains

```
  34.656,87.7565 ,78
```

size of this csv is 5gb

I'm using follwing commands to updated collection

```
 mongoimport --db test --collection nct_test --upsert --upsertFields band2 --file gdalexportedb8.csv
```

but I'm getting follwing error..

```
    Failed: error processing document #2: invalid character ',' looking for beginning of value
```

I want to know this is the right way or not and can anybody help me in this..

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your `CSV` file

- Add a new line at the beginning containing field names.

Regarding to your command

- Add these to your command: [`--type csv`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--type)[`--headerline`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--headerline)

for example:

```
$ cat > locations.csv
Name,Address,City,State,ZIP
Jane Doe,123 Main St,Whereverville,CA,90210
John Doe,555 Broadway Ave,New York,NY,10010
 ctrl-d
$ mongoimport -d mydb -c things --type csv --file locations.csv --headerline
connected to: 127.0.0.1
imported 3 objects
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 1.7.3
connecting to: test
> use mydb
switched to db mydb
> db.things.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d32a36ed63d057130c08fca"), "Name" : "Jane Doe", "Address" : "123 Main St", "City" : "Whereverville", "State" : "CA", "ZIP" : 90210 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d32a36ed63d057130c08fcb"), "Name" : "John Doe", "Address" : "555 Broadway Ave", "City" : "New York", "State" : "NY", "ZIP" : 10010 }
```

Comment: but this will result in lat ,long ,band2  value in collection ,,band1 value will be removed

Comment: It's not gonna merge any data, and apparently it's how mongoimport do! [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17405308/2586595)!